# how to resize a row template in datagrid by "altMobileResizer" in live code

Tags: livecode

I am developing an application for the Android,I phone and windows in LiveCode. In this I would like to automatically re size the content and stack according to device screen.I am using "altMobileresizer".I can re size images,text and groups.But i am not able to re size the content of a data grid.How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to include something in your resizeStack handler to call other handler(s) to work with the screen size of the device your app is running on, from there decide on some classification or size banding that your app should use for that particular device - and from there decide what font sizes etc to use in you datagrid. Once that is decided you need more code to amend the datagrid row template changing font sizes, control sizes, control positioning etc).

I would also include some sort of 'perform once on initial startup' trigger so that the code is is only called when it's needed.

From what you write it sounds like that altMobileResizer is not working with datagrids (I'm not surprised, they are are complex groupings) but it may be that you can hook into some of it's functionality so you do not have to code everything yourself (but even if you do, it's not so bad...)

There is lots of guidance on http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/datagrid - be prepared to spend a bit of time getting to know datagrids to get them working right (or, consider using a simple table instead - do you really need a datagrid?)

Comment: I am not getting anything helpful in above link that can solve this problem.Is there anything other that can be helpful?